# What does "binary" means in device driver?

Tags: c, embedded, linux-kernel, device-driver, linux-device-driver

I am very much new to Device driver programming.
I was going through below website.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/driverdev.aspx

I was just confused with the word "binary".
The particular statement says "The linker builds the final binary, and based on what the options are in the PE header....".
So my question is what does binary means in Device Driver programming?

Comment: It means the same as for every other program: machine code. If you really want to do *linux* programming as your tags suggest you might want to find another guide …

Comment: @filmor: Could please suggest me some good tutorials, who are providing good depth knowledge on Device driver programming along with some dummy code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly See [Binary File](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file) on Wikipedia

Generally a binary file is any file that stores data in a non-human readable format.
Therefore, word processor documents, spread sheets, databases and executable files (runnable program files) are all binary files (if you open them in a simple text editor, or echo them to the console, they don't make a lick of sense, they need another program or the OS to make sense of them).

In this instance "final binary file" would be the executable (or library file) that your [source code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code) is [compiled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) to.

None of this is linux specific, but is general across **all** computer artectures (and probably some pedant will point out a computer/OS where this doesn't apply, so *nearly all* or *all common* could replace the **all** above)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 5):

Binary means the compiled and linked object code, as opposed to the source code.